# Determine if definite integral of absolute value of sum is inner product

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, inner-products

Problem is to determine if following expression is inner product over space of continuous functions of form: $$ f: [-1,2] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$$
define:

$$(i) <f, g> = \int_{-1}^2 \lvert f(x) + g(x) \rvert dx$$

I know that integral of a product of two functions is inner product:
$$(ii)<f,g> = \int_{-1}^1 f(x)g(x)dx$$
Showing linearity in (ii) is one-liner, since two functions under integral sign are multiplied.
But in my case (i) there is a sum, so I'm stuck.
Thank you!

Comment: Take $f=-g$ to see that $-\langle f, f \rangle=0$.

Comment: Do you have $ \langle f,0 \rangle = 0$ for all $f$ ? If no, then it is not bilinear.